# Path splitting with std::regex

Tags: regex, c++11

I'm trying to split a path into elements. This is a circuit description hierarchical path. Elements are separated by dots. There are 3 possible types of elements (the full details are far more complicated than this, but those details don't matter and I can assume that the paths are well formed).

1. **Ordinary identifier**

The usual sort of thing, letters, digits, dollar, underscore.

2. **Extended identifiers**

These are delimited by backslashes. They can include pretty much anything, including spaces and dots. They can also include backslashes, which have to be doubled.

3. **Escaped identifiers**

These are delimited by a starting backslash and ending whitespace (space, tab or newline to be precise, though in practice the space is almost the only one ever used). They can include backslashes and dots but no spaces.

The overwhelming majoring of paths are composed only of elements of type 1. Pathological extended extended/escaped identifiers (containing the other terminating delimiter followed by dot) are also unlikely to occur in the wild.

The problem that I'm having is that both 1. and 2. can contain each others terminating delimiter.

The regex that I've come up with so far is

```
std::string re = "^("\
                 "[^ \\\\][^.]*"\
                 "|\\\\(?:\\\\\\\\|[^\\\\])+\\\\(?=\\.|$)"\
                 "|\\\\[^ ]+ (?=\\.|$)"\
                 ")\\.?";
```

[I'm not sure if raw strings with their added parentheses would make this clearer]

The first and last lines contain the capture parentheses and the optional dot separator

```
"[^ \\\\][^.]*"
```

This is for the ordinary identifiers. Starts with a non-space/non-backslash followed by zero or more non-dots.

```
"|\\\\(?:\\\\\\\\|[^\\\\])+\\\\(?=\\.|$)"
```

It's for extended identifiers. A backslash followed by one or more double-backslashes or non-backslashes, terminated by a backslash followed by a dot or end-of-string.

```
"|\\\\[^ ]+ (?=\\.|$)"
```

Lastly the escaped identifiers. A backslash followed by one or more non-spaces. Terminated by a space followed by a dot or end-of-string.

This seems to work on most examples, except for cases that look like this

```
R"(a.\b\. .c)"
```

This should capture

```
'a' '\b\. ' 'c'
```

But because the escaped identifier alternative is before the extended identifier one the captures are

'a' '\b\' with an unmatched ' .c' left over

Swapping the order of the escaped and extended identifier alternatives is not a solution. It would just lead to failures with paths like

```
R"(a.\b .\.c)"
```

Currently my solution is to check that the suffix matches after each match. In pseudocode

```
// re is the regex as above, re2 is the same with extended/escaped swapped
while (std::regex_search(test_str, match, re))
{
    get suffix
    if (suffix empty or suffix matches)
    {
        process capture
        set test_str to suffix
    }
    else
    {
        if (std::regex_search(test_str, match, re2))
        {
            get suffix
            if (suffix empty or suffix matches)
            {
                process capture
                set test_str to suffix
            }
        }
        else
        {
            we have a problem
        }
    }
}
```

So, other than doing backtracking at the match level as above, is there a reasonable way with lookahead to match each element with just one attempt?

Edit:
I bit the lookahead bullet. In short I added extra copies of the whole regex (without the lookahead) to the escaped/extended alternatives. I was also being a bit too lazy and lax with the ordinary identifiers. I don't want to match spaces or backslashes. That gives me

```
std::string re = "^("\
                 // 1st alternative ordinary identifier
                 // starts with underscore or letter followed by zero or more brackets, underscores, letters, digits, dollars
                 "[_a-zA-Z][[\\]_a-zA-Z0-9$]*"\
                 // 2nd alternative extended identifier
                 // starts with a backslash followed by one or more double backslashes or non-backslashes and ends with a backslash
                 "|\\\\(?:\\\\\\\\|[^\\\\])+\\\\"\
                 // 3rd alternative escaped identifier
                 // starts with a backslash followed by one or more non-spaces and ends with a space
                 "|\\\\[^ ]+ )"\
                 // followed by a positive lookahead for either end of string or dot followed by the alternation above
                 "(?=$|\\.(?:[_a-zA-Z][[\\]_a-zA-Z0-9$]*|\\\\(?:\\\\\\\\|[^\\\\])+\\\\|\\\\[^ ]+ )"\
                 // end of capture
                 ")"\
                 // if there is a dot, consume it
                 "\\.?";
```

I've been using [regular expressions 101](https://regex101.com) to analyse and debug this RE. It only supports PCRE/javascript/python/golang but it's fairly easy to use a common subset. I find the explanation useful as a hierarchical breakdown of the RE. I can then check that the components match what I intended, and caught a few errors, for instance with `[]` character lists. I also found the regex debugger quite useful (PCRE mode only). In particular you can see the point where either it doesn't match in the first place or it matches then backtracks past the match you expected.

Comment: Please read more carefully. This is not a filesystem path. Whilst I haven't tried Boost filesystem, I doubt that it will support elements that contain separators or even the use of dot for the separator.

Comment: Then I'll go with my usual ["spiel"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/spiel): There's a saying along the line of "I have a problem. I solved it with a regex. Now I have *two* problems". Regexes can be powerful and solve a few problems very well, but in most cases they bring more problems with them than they solve. If there is a non-regex solution always try that first.

Comment: I know that chestnut. We already have a rather long function in-house that tries to do this splitting, but it does a worse job than my regexes (modulo performance that I haven't measured). This requires a lot of context and backtracking that regexes do fairly well.

Comment: Honestly, whoever designed your path element spec should be fired.  Case 1 is easy.  Case 2 and 3, well...  if there is a `" "` followed by a non-dot before a space followed by a dot you can rule out 3.  If there is a backslash followed by anything but a backslash or dot, you can rule out 2.  `".\abc .def\."` You cannot determine that `.\abc .` is not a case 3 until you work out that if it is, then `.def\.` is illegal.  My question is "can I make this NP-hard", not "can I solve this with RE".

Comment: Wait, `R"(a.\b\. .c)"` -- that should be `"a"`, `"b\. "` `"c"` under the rules you described at the top.  not `"\b. "`.  Where is the mistake?

Comment: For each element, you can find the longest legal one of case 2 or case 3.  Can we prove that the longest legal one must be the valid one?  If so you have a chance.

Comment: @Yakk The identifiers for the path elements are defined in IEEE 1076.2008 IEEE Standard VHDL Language Reference Manual and IEEE 1800-2012 IEEE Standard for SystemVerilog—Unified Hardware Design, Specification, and Verification Language.

Comment: @Yakk The text was correct but one of the backslashes was being treated as markup. I've changed it to be code and it should be correct now.

Comment: @PaulFloyd So, they are what you get when hardware people design software?  :)

Comment: Ok, `R"(a.\b\. .c)"` should capture `R"a"`, `R"b\."`, `R"c"`, not `R"\b\. "`?  It is a type 3 -- so it starts with a `R"\"`, and stops at a `R" ."`, and everythign in the middle is identifier.

Comment: What is `R"(.\abc\.\def .)"`?  Under the rules you provided, that consistently parses as `"abc"`, `"def"` (rule 2 followed by rule 3), or `R"(abc\.\def)"` (one application of rule 3).

Comment: @Yakk x3 No comment on electronic engineers as that's what I read for my bachelors and doctorate sometime last century. R"(a.\b\. c)" should capture R"(a)" (case 1), not R"(b\.)" since it doesn't start with a backslash but it does contain one. The second element should be R"(\b\. )" and the last element should be R"(c)". R"(.\abc\.def .)" - there shouldn't be a leading dot as the paths are always absolute, nor a trailing one, though the regexes I've been using tolerate a trailing dot. So R"(\abc\.\def )" would give R"(\abc\)" and R"(\def )".

Comment: @PaulFloyd I think you mean `R("abc")`.  Why should it give `abc` and `\def` and not `abc\.\def`?  Add a rule in your question that clarifies why it gives two and not one path element.  In short, the rules as described *in your question* are ambiguous in the case.  Rule 3 when applied to `R("\abc\.\def ")` works, as does applying Rule 2 then Rule 3 to the 2nd half.

Comment: My mistake. That should be `R"(\abc\)"`. The backslashes are literal delimiters in the identifiers. Looking at it more, `R"(\abc\.\def )"` does seem ambiguous. It could be either one element of case 3 or two elements of case 2 and case 3. In this situation probably I need something like a heuristic to choose the latter.